# Throws error: XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Element_, expecting Comma_ or Rbrace_ or SemiColon

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
element html{
    element h1{"Product catalog"}
    element ul{let $file := xdmp:document-get("d:\users\tdu\xquery\cataloge.xml")
                for $prod in ($file/catalog/product)
                return element li {("number:",data($prod/number),", name:",data($prod/name))}
    }
}
```

Throws below error:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Element_, expecting Comma_ or Rbrace_ or SemiColon_

Comment: I am new in xquey and marklogic

Comment: I notice that you accepted what appears to be a ChatGPT or Bing Chat answer on this 5-year old question.  Your original answer on it probably shouldn't have been changed.  It's not a great idea to accept answers that didn't solve your problem (especially when you already solved your problem), especially nowadays when they could just be AI copy/paste.

Answer (score 4):

Missing `,`

This should be as:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
element html{
  element h1{"Product catalog"},
  element ul{
            let $file := xdmp:document-get("d:\users\tdu\xquery\cataloge.xml")
            for $prod in ($file/catalog/product)
            return element li {("number:",data($prod/number),", name:",data($prod/name))}
  }
}
```